# Ruby on a Mac -- Regular Expression Spanning Two Lines of Text

Tags: ruby, regex, cross-platform

On the PC, the following Ruby regular expression matches data. However, when run on the Mac against the same input text file, no matches occur. Am I matching line returns in a way that should work cross-platform?

```
data = nil
File.open(ARGV[0], "r") do |file|
    data = file.readlines.join("").scan(/^Name: (.*?)[\r\n]+Email: (.*?)$/)
end
```

*Versions*
PC: ruby 1.9.2p135
Mac: ruby 1.8.6

Thank you,
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the ^ and $ pattern characters! Ruby doesn't consider \r (a.k.a. ^M) a line boundary.  If I modified my pattern, replacing both ^ and $ with "\r", the pattern matched as desired.

```
data = file.readlines.join.scan(/\rName: (.*?)\rEmail: (.*?)\r/)
```

Instead of modifying the pattern, I opted to do a gsub on the text, replacing \r with \n before calling scan.

```
data = file.readlines.join.gsub(/\r/, "\n").scan(/^Name: (.*?)\nEmail: (.*?)$/)
```

Thank you each for your responses to my question.

Answer (score 1):

When going from Windows -> Unix based (MAC) I've had this issue: [^M =? \r\n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems). The Carriage return gets rendered as a Control-M which may or may not be interpreted correctly by your regexp~

Comment: +1. That regex should work the same whatever the actual line separator is: `\r\n`, `\n` or `\r`.  It could be that either the data or the regex itself has been munged in the process of moving it.

Answer (score 0):

On Unix (OS X is a Unix), end of lines are \n, not \r\n. Putting simply [\n] will work on Mac.
To have a cross-platform script, may be you could first replace each \r\n sequence by a \n character?

Comment: `[\r\n]+` will match `\r` `\n` AND `\r\n`

Comment: Maybe scan(/^Name: (.*?)(\r?\n)+Email: (.*?)$/) should do the trick (you will capture the \n or the \r\n in data, though – jaco 12 mins ago